# how to prevent multiple play using mediaplayer javafx?

Tags: javafx

i have a problem in the performance of the songs. I have a list of audio tracks loaded from filechooser, placed in a TableView and stored in a list (players). by getSelectionModel take the selected audio file and I run it, so far so good. if you do not stop and I select another audio file and send you to play, The sounds is superimposed. How I can to stop the execution of the previous file thus avoiding a multiplay?

addFileAudio code:

```
 Media media;
 final List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();
 String fileName;
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public void addFileAudio(ActionEvent event) {
            BasicFileAttributes attr = null;
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Seleziona il file da caricare");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files","*.wav","*.mp3"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
        if (selectedFile != null) {

            media = new Media(new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()).toURI().toString());
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            players.add(mediaPlayer);

            MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
            mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

            Path pathFile = Paths.get(selectedFile.toURI());
            try {
                attr = Files.readAttributes(pathFile, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Exception.showError(1);
            }
        }else{
                Exception.showWarning(0);
        }

        String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
        String data = attr.creationTime().toString().substring(0,10);
        Table1.getItems().add(new PopulateTable(Table1.getItems().size()+1, fileName, data));

      }
```

code play button:

```
    void play(ActionEvent event) { 
MediaPlayer player = players.get(Table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()); Status status = player.getStatus(); 
if (status!= Status.PLAYING) { 
player.play();
 } else { 
MediaPlayer playerNext = players.get(Table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()); player.stop(); playerNext.play(); }
```

---

Comment: Status status should not be inside your play() method. It should be static and global. Then once you press play() you  play you song and then set the status to playing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe something like this:**
**UPDATE**

```
@FXML private ListView lvPlaylist;


MediaPlayer player;
Media pick;

Status status = Status.STOPPED;

String pathToMP3One = "song1.mp3";
String pathToMP3Two = "song2.mp3";

HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap();

ObservableList<String> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList ();


@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    switch(status)
    {
        case STOPPED:

            String fileToPlay = hashmap.get(lvPlaylist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
            System.out.println(fileToPlay);
            pick = new Media(fileToPlay);
            player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
            player.play();
            status = Status.PLAYING;
            break;
        case PLAYING:
            player.stop();
            fileToPlay = hashmap.get(lvPlaylist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
            pick = new Media(fileToPlay);
            player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
            player.play();
            status = Status.PLAYING;
            break;                
    }
}

@FXML
public void addFileAudio(ActionEvent event) {
    BasicFileAttributes attr = null;
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Seleziona il file da caricare");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files","*.wav","*.mp3"));
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        Path pathFile = Paths.get(selectedFile.toURI());
        try {
            attr = Files.readAttributes(pathFile, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    hashmap.put(selectedFile.getName(), selectedFile.toURI().toString());     
    System.out.println("File name: " + selectedFile.getName());
    lvPlaylist.getItems().add(selectedFile.getName());

  }
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    lvPlaylist.setItems(items);

}
```

This worked for me!

Comment: thank you, but the method setStatus give me an error:
the method setStatus from the type MediaPlayer is not visible
what do you suggest me?

Comment: I am guessing you have a method setStatus(). Just get rid of player.setStatus(); part. You have player.getStatus(); so I assumed that you must have player.setStatus(); Sorry. If you don't have a player.setStatus(),  how do you ever change the status of the player. Why use player.getStatus if it's always the same.

Comment: In fact I can not change the value only to take it. I have a statusProperty () method but I can not figure out if it is in my case. You can also use only STATUS. (Stopped / Paused / Playing ...)

Comment: ok it works, but only the first time! the second time share overlapping ..

Comment: I would have to see the error code to have an idea what the problem is. I am guessing you may need to learn about thread? I am curious about what is going on in the player class.

Comment: does not show any error in the console, it actually works ...
But it play the first sound, when I click on the second, the software stops running the first audio and plays the second. At this point when I select again the first audio and send it in play, I return to me the problem of overlapping audio.

Comment: I am going to create a little sample to see what's going on.

Comment: hello, thank you for availability, I'm sorry to have to disturb yet but I can not create the object items. why I'm using an ArrayList of type mediaPlayer ... I post the code of input file(update my question), you can give me some advice , please?

Comment: If you are using File chooser you can delete String pathToMP3One = "song1.mp3";
String pathToMP3Two = "song2.mp3";